# Is there an advanced console for Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, console

I have been using cmd.exe and I feel it's very clumsy when it comes to copy ,paste or for navigation. 
I feel there can be a better console which increases productivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [conemu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/), it presents a lot of awesome features

Answer (score 0):

- [conemu](https://conemu.codeplex.com/), and  [here is how it looks](http://conemu.github.io/en/Screenshots.html)

or

- [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).